# Приведение параметризованных типов

Tags: java, generics, типы

В сервлете необходимо получить инстанс `DAO` который обернут в `AtomicReference`, но при приведении типов компилятор волнуется и пишет:

```
Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference<ru.javavision.dao.UserDAO>' less... (⌘F1) 
Signals places where an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler, for example:

  void f(HashMap map) {
    map.put("key", "value");
  }

Hint: Pass -Xlint:unchecked to javac to get more details.
```

Сам код выглядит так:

```
AtomicReference<UserDAO> dao = (AtomicReference<UserDAO>) req.getServletContext().getAttribute("dao");
```

Подскажите как можно успокоить компилятор, учитывая что `instance of` не работает с дженериками, или если работает то как это написать?

Спасибо.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9188666/5812238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать аннотацию `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.